# Hibernate. Как получить время и дату из базы данных?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, дата

В базе данных есть поле с именем arrival_time и типом DATETIME. В записях в базе данных это поле выглядит как '2017-02-01 12:15:00', но из объекта я получаю сокращенную запись в виде 2017-02-01, без времени. С полем arrival_time у меня ассоциировано поле типа java.sql.Date, т.е. значение из DATETIME записывается в java.sql.Date и я получаю дату без времени...

Пробовал делать так: new Date(schedule.getTime().getTime()), где первый getTime() возвращает ассоциированный с DATETIME объект java.sql.Date, но в таком случае 
дата сохраняется, а время принимает вид 00:00:00.

Буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: Вам нужен `java.util.Date` или `java.sql.Timestamp`. А `java.sql.Date` время обнуляет, о чём честно говориться в документации этого класса https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html

Comment: @Sergey сработало, спасибо!